# How can i use the "for loop" for a chemical iteration?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, calculation

I have the problem that I can't figure out how to write my loop code.

```
n_masssection = 100
    
for i in range(n_masssection):
   
    dn_New = dn_Sample(CO_in, H2O_in, H2_in, CO2_in)
    n_New = dn_Pronew(CO_in, H2O_in, H2_in, CO2_in, dn_New)
    dn_New1 = dn_Sample(n_New[0], n_New[1], n_New[2], n_New[3])
    n_New1 = dn_Pronew(n_New[0], n_New[1], n_New[2], n_New[3], dn_New1)
```

"dn_Sample, dn_Pronew" are functions. "dn_Sample" returns a value that  is used for the calculation of "n_Pronew". "n_Proneu" calculates 4 new gas concentrations which should be placed in the next "section" so calculate a ne dn_New with ne Sample function but now with the new gas concentrations. I want that my loop should do this 100 times... but I don't know how to do that without writing new objects for every calculation, which would take a lot of time.

Can someone help me with this?

I had the idea to save the results in the loop but my functions always need there 4|5 arguments to calculate. How to replace theme with the results of the calculation of the function before them.

Comment: Save each result in a list and return the full list. If you want to add a key for each result, you can also use a `dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n_masssection = 100
t = (CO_in, H2O_in, H2_in, CO2_in)

res = [t]
for i in range(n_masssection):
    dn_New = dn_Sample(*res[-1])
    n_New = n_Pronew(*res[-1], dn_New)
    dn_New1 = dn_Sample(*n_New)
    n_New1 = n_Pronew(*n_New, dn_New1)
    res.append(n_New1)
```

Then, I think res is your final result.

Comment: Yes but i want that i get the n_New100, after 100 masssections. This solution would give me the concentration after 2 calculations.

Comment: I modify the answer, so res contains all 100 result of the problem.